# How to track IIS server performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

I have a reoccurring issue where a customer calls up and complains that the web site is too slow.  Specifically, if they are inactive for a short period of time, then go back to the site, there will be a minute-two minute delay before the user sees a response. (the standard browser is Firefox in this case)

I have Perfmon up and running, the cpu utilization is usually below 20% (single proc...don't ask).  The database is humming along.  And I'm pulling my hair out.

So, what metrics/tools do you find useful when evaluating IIS performance?

Comment: This might be a better fit on Server Fault.

Comment: Could be, but Server Fault did not exist when I asked this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hope this helps:
[Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
[Scaling Strategies for ASP.NET Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/april/performance-scaling-strategies-for-asp-net-applications)
[IIS Tuning](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a660b95-7f2f-4ac2-bf1f-a9f7b9b9d813/iis-6-performance-tweak-guide-draft?forum=iis56performance)
[14 Rules for Faster-Loading Web Sites](https://web.archive.org/web/20191222013709/http://stevesouders.com:80/hpws/rules.php)
[Best practices for creating websites in IIS 6.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20131201020015/http://msmvps.com:80/blogs/omar/archive/2008/10/04/best-practices-for-creating-websites-in-iis-6-0.aspx)
[Stanford Computer Cience - High Performance Web Sites](http://cs193h.stevesouders.com/)
[10 Tips for Writing High-Performance Web Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/january/asp-net-10-tips-for-writing-high-performance-web-applications)
[Writing High-Performance Managed Applications : A Primer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973858%28v=msdn.10%29)
[Nine tips for a healthy "in production" ASP.NET application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dougste/)
[Speedy C#, Part 2: Optimizing Memory Allocations - Pooling and Reusing Objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117124801/http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/08/07/speedy-c-part-2-optimizing-memory-allocations---pooling-and.aspx)
[Memory Usage Auditing For .NET Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20190112075112/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882521.aspx)
[Troubleshooting HTTP Compression in IIS 6.0](https://iis-blogs.azurewebsites.net/webtopics/troubleshooting-http-compression-in-iis-6-0)
[Maximizing IIS Performance - 25 tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb742459%28v=technet.10%29)
[Optimizing IIS 6.0 Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc728451%28v=ws.10%29)
[Page Speed - an open-source Firefox/Firebug Add-on](https://developers.google.com/speed?csw=1)
[Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/Performance_Testing_Guidance_for_Web_Applications)
[Top 10 Performance Improvements in IIS 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc745952%28v=msdn.10%29)
[CHAPTER 6 Optimizing IIS 6.0 Performance](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5135)
[Performance Tuning Guidelines for Windows Server 2003 - Performance Tuning for IIS 6.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20171115041724/http://www.microsoft.com:80/windowsserver2003/evaluation/performance/tuning.mspx)
[ASP.NET Performance Tips](http://aspalliance.com/1533_ASPNET_Performance_Tips.7)
[IIS 6.0 Tuning for Performance - by Peter A. Bromberg, Ph.D.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210916100053/http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20050613.asp)
[Improving .NET Application Performance and Scalability - by MS](https://web.archive.org/web/20220921114142/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11711)
[Optimizing and Performance Tuning IIS 6.0](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=335881)
[12 Steps To Faster Web Pages With Visual Round Trip Analyzer](https://web.archive.org/web/20150112070311/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/magazine/dd188562.aspx)
[Thread: IIS 6 performance tweak guide (draft)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a660b95-7f2f-4ac2-bf1f-a9f7b9b9d813/iis-6-performance-tweak-guide-draft?forum=iis56performance)
[CPU Settings for an Application Pool   IIS6 e IIS7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/cpu)

Great improvements tips :
[Running ASMX Web Services on STA Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/october/wicked-code-running-asmx-web-services-on-sta-threads)
[Scale Net](https://download.microsoft.com/download/a/7/e/a7ea6fd9-2f56-439e-a8de-024c968f26d1/ScaleNet.pdf)

Measure, measure, measure :
Load Test Your Site
[Show Slow](https://github.com/sergeychernyshev/showslow/wiki)
[Performance Monitor Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24832)
[Two Minute Drill: Introduction to XPerf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/)
[Suggested Performance Counters to Watch (IIS 6.0)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170204085633/http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7898b860-462c-4846-a3a8-1179f287ad88.mspx?mfr=true)

See what the best sites did :
[Benchmarks](https://web.archive.org/web/20130423235614/http://www.gomez.com/benchmarks/)
[TOP 100](https://www.alexa.com/topsites?cc=US&ts_mode=country&lang=none)

More resource :
[Learn papers](https://web.archive.org/web/20110414005237/http://www.gomez.com/resources/)

My experience says:

- Enable compression (GZIP/Deflate) in IIS, for Static data. Simple to implement and with excellent results.
- if cpu is not your problem try to enable compression for dynamic data as well.

Comment: ok lots of links is good, but what about some advice based on *your* experience, too?

Comment: My experience says: Evaluate each case and apply that brings results. I am giving the options.

Answer (score 12):

For your particular case, you need to increase the idle-timeout option in IIS because that delay is due to ASP.NET loading the binaries and starting your application.  The default is 20 minutes, so if nobody accesses the site for 20 minutes, IIS will shut down the process and the next request will take a long time to start up.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for what to set the value to?
I changed mine to 60 minutes as a starter.

Comment: It depends on how much traffic your site receives. I would say set if you are receiving < 100 visitors/day it should be about 24hrs. This way if you don't receive any traffic in the off peak time your site will still be responsive the next day.

Comment: @Chris you normally don't want it to timeout at all if you're running your own server and there isn't much else on the box. You always want your site to be snappy right?

Comment: I suggest setting the timeout to 1440 (one full day)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the application pool is shutting down when there is a period of inactivity? The application pool would take some time to start back up.