# Determining what is putting pressure on IIS

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

I got a dedicated server running both IIS 7.5 and SQL Server 2010. Server CPU load is often near 100%. The SQL server does not take too much but the w3wp process is taking a significant amount of CPU (often 70+%).

I'd like to find out, what is causing this pressure: 
* Too many requests of static files (a CDN could be added)
* Too many ajax requests (I am thinking about comet/web sockets anyways)
* Single asp.net pages consuming too much processing power (should be easy to optimize)

Where would you start looking to find out where to start optimizing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to track IIS server performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660589/how-to-track-iis-server-performance)

Comment: This is not so much information's. How many web do you have setup ? how many users are connected at the same moment ? How many database and how big they are ? How threads is your cpu, and how much memory do you have ? I have see a case where the server was under attack and a bot was creating users on a not good protected web app and make millions of blog with bad stuff. Can you check if you have a case like that ? or all that are come from normal users ?

Comment: Everything is normal, no attack. There is enough RAM (16 GB, IIS uses less than 1GB, 3GB are unused)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest possible way is to profile the app in production. Not sure if that is possible in your case. Some options:

- look into the logs and look at the duration of the requests. Long requests are likely to put load on the system
- Remote debug w3wp with Visual Studio and pause the debugger 10 times to see where it stops most. That is the hot spot
- Use XPerf or PerfView to capture (managed) stacks. This has almost no impact on production performance

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to figure it out would be to install [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) on the server.  The trial lasts 30 days I think so it should give you enough time to get to the bottom of this.  It'll show you long-running SQL queries, .NET methods, as well as just about everything else you can think of.  It makes it very easy to identify bottlenecks.

---

By the way, I suggested New Relic because it sounds like your problem is in a production environment.  New Relic isn't an incredibly detailed profiler.  It gathers enough information to be helpful, but not so much as to slow down the server.  That makes it well suited to this purpose.

If, however, you could reproduce the problem in a development environment you might try something like the free [Eqatec profiler](http://eqatec.com/Profiler/).

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be to fire up the development tools (F12 in IE / Chrome) and look at the timings under the network tab. That will show you a waterfall-style diagram for how the page has loaded and should help you identify any particularly slow-loading static files which might be sensibly moved off to a cdn, any unnecessary requests being made, how much time is being spent getting the actual page itself, etc.

After that, profile the application with a performance profiler. A good profiler like [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler) will let you look at things like execution time / hit counts for different methods, as well as what database queries are being run and how long they’re taking. A new version of ANTS (currently in [EAP](http://help.red-gate.com/help/ANTSPerformanceProfiler/download_eap.html)) will also group that activity by http request so you can see if specific pages need optimisation or are being hit too many times.

You'd also do well to check that caching is working as you intend it so that users aren’t unnecessarily re-requesting pages.

There's also a nice article on ASP.NET performance which you might want to read at http://aspalliance.com/1533_ASPNET_Performance_Tips.7.

Disclaimer: I work for Red Gate which makes ANTS.

Comment: From the user point of view the site is quick, so the developer tools on the browser side don't help. But yes, I should go and use a tool like ANTS. (or dotTrace :)) but so far I wasn't sure if and how to use that on the production server. I dabbled around years ago on the development server but there I don't have relevant usage data.

Comment: As a rule of thumb you should try to avoid profiling on production where possible because of the added performance impact on an already heavily loaded system. That said, it's sometimes a necessary evil and in reality people do it successfully all the time.If you do this in the future you can use the 'Attach to Process' option to avoid having to restart IIS. You can also use a lower sampling strategy to lessen the performance impact: for example you'd probably want to avoid line-level timing in production unless really necessary, whereas method level timing would probably be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to see what's going on on the server. 
Nevertheless, the professional way is probably to go and use a profiling tool.

What did I do?
In IIS Console you can get a list of all current worker threads and if you choose one you can see what this thread is working on. So I was able to see that the thread was handling 100 requests in parallel, 70 of those were tracing back to the same ajax call.

The immediate solution was to reduce the frequency of that call (from every 10 to every 30 seconds). The next step will be to further optimize the call on the server side since I do have other ajax calls with the same frequency (every 10 seconds) which nearly never showed up in the active requests list since they were so fast.

Comment: Now that you have some idea what you're looking for, check out the Eqatec profiler I mention in my answer.  They have a free version.