# Improving performance in IIS request

Tags: asp.net, performance, logging, iis, optimization

We are working on performance improvements. I have enabled trace using Failed Request tracing.
We are getting delay in **General Read Entity Start** and **General Read Entity End** events in most of our request.

After some searching, few says it might be helpful to increase the

`<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="someLargevalue" />`

Default is 4k
I increased that to maximum. but no effect.

My question is how can i improve this request processing time. Most of the time,optim it takes 1.5 sec

Below is the log
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660589/how-to-track-iis-server-performance/660672

Answer (score 0):

You can try below ways to improve ASP.NET web application performance by IIS settings:

1. Disable IIS logging.
2. Enable HTTP Compression in IIS.
3. Enable Output Caching in IIS.
4. ASP Queue Length property.

More information about Optimizing IIS Performance you can refer to this link: [Optimizing IIS Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/optimizing-iis-performance).

Comment: We have applied most of these ways, but getting the delay in events mentioned in my question. i am asking what are those events that is causing the delay. the delay is not consistent.

Comment: If you want to know the detailed reasons for the delay, you can use Fiddler for a more in-depth study.